# Javascript d3.js binding click event with 'immediate invoked function'

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events

I am trying to keep track of which circle in a d3 graph is being clicked, for which I used the following code which works as expected:

```
var svg = d3.select('#test');

    for (var i=0; i < 5; i++){
        svg.append('circle')
            .attr('r', 5)
            .attr('cx', function(){return 10+ i*11} )
            .attr('cy', 10)
            .on('click', 
                function(d){
                    return function(){console.log(d)}
                }(i)
            );
    }
```

Now I want to reuse part of the code with the only change being the function for the click event. I tried to do the following:

```
    function logging(){
        console.log(d);
    }

    for (var i=0; i < 5; i++){
        svg.append('circle')
            .attr('r', 5)
            .attr('cx', function(){return 10+ i*11} )
            .attr('cy', 30)
            .style('fill', 'purple')
            .on('click', 
                function(d){
                    return logging
                }(i)
            );
    }
```

But this does not work as I expected it. It logs undefined in stead of 0,1,2,3 or 4. I have tried different version with parenthesis, extra arguments, `var loggin = function....`, but I cannot get it to work.

Fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/t1vhvLqy/

Comment: Can you pass a IIFE as a function argument? I do know that for an IIFE to work you need to make it an expression and not a statement `(function(d){ return logging;}(i))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example works because the IIFE creates a closure that calls the log function with the correct argument, namely `d` set to the current value of `i`.

Your second example example does return a function (`logging`) but without any closure, the code is equivalent to `.on('click', logging)`.

To make this work as you intend, just replace `console.log` with a call to your function, for example

```
.on('click', 
    (function(d){
        return function(){ logging(d); }
    })(i)
)
```

And a demo https://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/t1vhvLqy/1/